# Google Analytics not working on my ASP.NET MVC Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

I am trying to use `Google Analytics` on my MVC page. I have added the provided script in the head of my layout.cshtml page. [This is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539152/google-analytics-code-is-the-correct-place-to-put-it-in-an-mvc-5-app) that I based it on.

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new 
Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-
analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', '__-_________-_', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

I check the network on the browser and I can see analytics.js being called when I go to any page. But the google analytics site is not showing any changes.

Am I missing something?

Edit 1 : Also I have two such code scripts in my code. One for test site and one for production. Will that affect working of the script?

Comment: can you pls send an example of the html page? and by the way you can put that script at the end of your body html tag

Comment: Try [debugging it](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/debugging)

Comment: Also, the official [advice on how to set this all up is here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) be wary of non-official links. Google like to move the goal posts on this kind of stuff quite often, though they are mostly quite good at keeping backwards compatibility for a time.